# Date from datepicker flips day and month

Tags: java, android, datepicker

When I select a date from datepicker the day and month a flipping positions.I want mm/dd/yyyy. Instead I am getting dd/mm/yyyy.

I tried a few methods described on this site to fix it but it didn't help. Such as HOUR_OF_DAY, instead of HOUR. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Any advice, suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import sync.DatabaseHandler;
import sync.UserFunctions;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Register extends Activity {


    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_DOB = "dob";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;
    //Datpicker setup
    Button dateButton;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    private DatePicker dobPicker;
    TextView dobResultView;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    String dob;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNameInput);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameInput);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);
        dobPicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dobSelect);
        dateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dateBtn);
        dobResultView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dobResultView);
        setCurrentDateOnView();


/**
 * Return to login screen
 **/

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast on fields if empty.
         **/
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                dob = " ("+Integer.toString(day)+"/"+Integer.toString(month+1)+"/"+Integer.toString(year)+")";
               dobResultView.setText(dob);
            }
        });

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    NetAsync(view);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
       }
    /**
     * Async Task check internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }





    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

/**
 * Defining Process dialog
 **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String email,password,fname,lname,dob;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
           fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
           lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
           email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
           dobPicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dobSelect);
           dobResultView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dobResultView);
           dob = Integer.toString(day)+"/"+Integer.toString(month+1)+"/"+Integer.toString(year);
           password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
           pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
           pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           pDialog.setCancelable(true);
           pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, dob, password);
            return json;
        }

       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       /**
        * Checks for success message.
        **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_DOB),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Settings screen to complete setup
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                        **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);
                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                    else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }

       }
    }

    public void NetAsync(View view){
            new NetCheck().execute();

    }

 // display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        dobPicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dobSelect);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



        // set current date into datepicker
        dobPicker.init(year, month, day, null);

    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
           // set date picker as current date
           return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
                = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
             year = selectedYear;
             month = selectedMonth;
             day = selectedDay;

             dobPicker.init(year, month, day, null);
             dob = " ("+Integer.toString(day)+"/"+Integer.toString(month+1)+"/"+Integer.toString(year)+")";
             dobResultView.setText(dob);
        }
    };

}
```

Code for view: regiser.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#6ec782"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registerInstructView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/registerInstructTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordInput"
    android:layout_below="@+id/registerInstructView"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstNameInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordInput"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordInput"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailInput"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lastNameInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstNameInput"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstNameInput"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastNameView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lastNameInput"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lastNameInput"
    android:text="@string/lastNameTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstNameView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lastNameInput"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/firstNameInput"
    android:text="@string/firstNameTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/register_error"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/registerBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:textColor="#e30000"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/passwordTxtView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/firstNameInput"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/firstNameView"
    android:text="@string/passwordTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailTxtView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailInput"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordTxtView"
    android:text="@string/emailTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dobResultView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dobSelect"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dobSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dateBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dateBtn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dobResultView"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:text="@string/registerBtnTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dateBtn"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lastNameInput"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="@string/dateBtnTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/register_error"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/register_error"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerBtn"
    android:text="@string/loginBtnTxt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are
 using   `dob = " ("+Integer.toString(day)+"/"+Integer.toString(month+1)+"/"+Integer.toString(year)+")";`
instead of that use  `("+Integer.toString(month+1)+"/"+Integer.toString(day)+"/"+Integer.toString(year)+")";`

Comment: Of course! ::Smacks hand against head:: I completely missed it, but it's so obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change this lines

```
dobPicker.init(year, month, day, null);
             dob = " ("+Integer.toString(month+1)+"/"+Integer.toString(day)+"/"+Integer.toString(year)+")";
             dobResultView.setText(dob);
```

Answer (score 1):

The onCreateDialog is deprecated now.

```
  @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
           // set date picker as current date
           return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Use Fragment to show the Dialog as follows :

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        month = month + 1;
        if (month < 10) {
            txtBirthday.setText(day + "-" + "0" + month + "-" + year);
        } else {
            txtBirthday.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
        }
    }
}
```

It will show the date as you requested.

You can call the class as like the following (in any onClickListener )

```
txtBirthday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
});
```

`txtBirthDay` is the textview here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll give a try, but I'm not having any errors or anything with using the dialog.